# Bind events within Kendo grid

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I need to bind some events on the grid row and details view. I'm using an observable view model with some events registered and trying to bind them to the DOM using row template and details templates. So far no progress.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    sortable:true,
    rowTemplate:'<tr class="k-master-row"> 
         <td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="k-icon k-plus" href=""></a></td>
        <td><a data-bind:"click:highlight">click in row ${id}</a></td><td>${bool}</td>
    </tr>',
    detailTemplate:'<a data-bind:"click:highlight">click In details ${id}</a>',
    columns: [{field:'id',sortable:false}, {field:'bool'}],
    dataBound: function(e) {
      var grid=$("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
      grid.expandRow("tr.k-master-row");
    }
});


var model=( {
    highlight:function(){
       console.log(this.id);
    },
   items:[{id: 1123, bool: true}, {id: 223, bool: false}]
});
kendo.bind($("#grid"),kendo.observable(model));
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amGmr/9/  . Is there any possibility to bind events withing the grid using MVVM ?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? Can you please post the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify the events you wish to bind to via the data-bind attribute and the events binding:

```
<div data-role="grid" 
     data-bind="source: dataSource, events:{dataBound: dataBound, detailInit: detailInit}"
></div>

<script>
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
   dataBound: function(e) {
      var grid = e.sender; // `this` is the viewModel instance
   },
   detailInit: function(e) {
       var grid = e.sender; // `this` is the viewModel instance
   },
   dataSource: [ 
      { name: "John Doe" },
      { name: "Jane Doe" }
   ]
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me using kendo v2015.2.805 I also tried the non mvvm way of defining the dataBound handler on the options prior to grid creation.

Comment: Given solution doesn't solve click:highlight event issue.